# Importing information from a textfile into a database

Tags: mysql, database

So, I have a text file formatted like this:

```html
id, username, welcomemsg, contactemail

1 supercoolusername37 welcomemsg0 john@gmail.com
2 anotherusername49 welcomemsg1 jimmy@gmail.com
```

So, it kinda looks like that.

I made a MySQL database, with a table but I don't know how to "Tell" / do mysql to say that for each space, insert into it's each own column. I'm terrible at explaining things, but how do I import a textfile like that into a MySQL table?
I'd appreciate any help so much!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loading-tables.html

Comment: took me a while to understand it but i got it now. Thank you!